# open -a Terminal filename argument doesn't work at all, on mac osx

Tags: macos, terminal, arguments, exec

I'm trying to open a C file already compiled using
open -a Terminal filename argument
It's actually a simple server.c file.
I need also to pass the port as argument, but i can't find out how to do it.

"open -a Terminal proxy 8000"
it returns: "The file /Users/...../8000 does not exist."
So i've tried:
"open -a Terminal proxy\ 8000"
it returns: "The file /Users/...../proxy 8000 does not exist."

Of course if i do "./proxy 8000"
It works.

So i definitely need to pass di parameter as argument in command line, but i can't find out any help even in stackoverflow.
Any help? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The open command is meant to open simple files, it doesn't really support your use case. There's an --args option that passes arguments to the application it uses to open the file (i.e. Terminal), but it doesn't look like Terminal passes those on.

AppleScript might work for you though, e.g. from the shell:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "/path/to/proxy 8000"'
```

Comment: Ok got it, it works like that
tell application "Terminal"
 activate
 do script "/myPath/proxy 8000"
end tell

Nice! Thanks!!